# From C to C++: function was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, c

I'm importing some methods from a C library to use them in my C++ main code but I have compilation errors:

```
$ make
g++ -c main.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:419:67: error: ‘kmedoids’ was not declared in this scope
 kmedoids(class_num, N, distanceMatrix, 1, clusterid, error, ifound);
                                                                   ^
main.cpp: In function ‘void kmedoids(int, int, double**, int, int*, double*, int*)’:
main.cpp:537:64: error: ‘randomassign’ was not declared in this scope
     if (npass!=0) randomassign(nclusters, nelements, tclusterid);
                                                                ^
main.cpp:550:42: error: ‘getclustermedoids’ was not declared in this scope
                         centroids, errors);
                                          ^
main.cpp: In function ‘void randomassign(int, int, int*)’:
main.cpp:644:20: error: ‘binomial’ was not declared in this scope
   j = binomial(n, p);
                    ^
main.cpp:654:40: error: ‘uniform’ was not declared in this scope
 { j = (int) (i + (nelements-i)*uniform());
                                        ^
main.cpp: In function ‘int binomial(int, double)’:
main.cpp:704:24: error: ‘uniform’ was not declared in this scope
     double u = uniform();
                        ^
main.cpp:732:26: error: ‘uniform’ was not declared in this scope
       double u = uniform();
                          ^
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

this is the last part of my code with the new C methods:

```
#include "profileManager.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
//......PREVIOUS CODE.......

kmedoids(class_num, N, distanceMatrix, 1, clusterid, error, ifound);

    return 0;
}



//NEW C METHODS
void kmedoids (int nclusters, int nelements, double** distmatrix,
  int npass, int clusterid[], double* error, int* ifound)
{ int i, j, icluster;
  int* tclusterid;
  int* saved;
  int* centroids;
  double* errors;
  int ipass = 0;

  if (nelements < nclusters)
  { *ifound = 0;
    return;
  } /* More clusters asked for than elements available */

  *ifound = -1;

  /* We save the clustering solution periodically and check if it reappears */
  saved = (int*)malloc(nelements*sizeof(int));
  if (saved==NULL) return;

  centroids = (int*)malloc(nclusters*sizeof(int));
  if(!centroids)
  { free(saved);
    return;
  }

  errors = (double*)malloc(nclusters*sizeof(double));
  if(!errors)
  { free(saved);
    free(centroids);
    return;
  }

  /* Find out if the user specified an initial clustering */
  if (npass<=1) tclusterid = clusterid;
  else
  { tclusterid = (int*)malloc(nelements*sizeof(int));
    if(!tclusterid)
    { free(saved);
      free(centroids);
      free(errors);
      return;
    }
  }

  *error = DBL_MAX;
  do /* Start the loop */
  { double total = DBL_MAX;
    int counter = 0;
    int period = 10;

    if (npass!=0) randomassign(nclusters, nelements, tclusterid);
    while(1)
    { double previous = total;
      total = 0.0;

      if (counter % period == 0) /* Save the current cluster assignments */
      { for (i = 0; i < nelements; i++) saved[i] = tclusterid[i];
        if (period < INT_MAX / 2) period *= 2;
      }
      counter++;

      /* Find the center */
      getclustermedoids(nclusters, nelements, distmatrix, tclusterid,
                        centroids, errors);

      for (i = 0; i < nelements; i++)
      /* Find the closest cluster */
      { double distance = DBL_MAX;
        for (icluster = 0; icluster < nclusters; icluster++)
        { double tdistance;
          j = centroids[icluster];
          if (i==j)
          { distance = 0.0;
            tclusterid[i] = icluster;
            break;
          }
          tdistance = (i > j) ? distmatrix[i][j] : distmatrix[j][i];
          if (tdistance < distance)
          { distance = tdistance;
            tclusterid[i] = icluster;
          }
        }
        total += distance;
      }
      if (total>=previous) break;
      /* total>=previous is FALSE on some machines even if total and previous
       * are bitwise identical. */
      for (i = 0; i < nelements; i++)
        if (saved[i]!=tclusterid[i]) break;
      if (i==nelements)
        break; /* Identical solution found; break out of this loop */
    }

    for (i = 0; i < nelements; i++)
    { if (clusterid[i]!=centroids[tclusterid[i]])
      { if (total < *error)
        { *ifound = 1;
          *error = total;
          /* Replace by the centroid in each cluster. */
          for (j = 0; j < nelements; j++)
            clusterid[j] = centroids[tclusterid[j]];
        }
        break;
      }
    }
    if (i==nelements) (*ifound)++; /* break statement not encountered */
  } while (++ipass < npass);

  /* Deallocate temporarily used space */
  if (npass > 1) free(tclusterid);

  free(saved);
  free(centroids);
  free(errors);

  return;
}


static void randomassign (int nclusters, int nelements, int* clusterid)
{ int i, j;
int k = 0;
double p;
int n = nelements-nclusters;
/* Draw the number of elements in each cluster from a multinomial
 * distribution, reserving ncluster elements to set independently
 * in order to guarantee that none of the clusters are empty.
 */
for (i = 0; i < nclusters-1; i++)
{ p = 1.0/(nclusters-i);
  j = binomial(n, p);
  n -= j;
  j += k+1; /* Assign at least one element to cluster i */
  for ( ; k < j; k++) clusterid[k] = i;
}
/* Assign the remaining elements to the last cluster */
for ( ; k < nelements; k++) clusterid[k] = i;

/* Create a random permutation of the cluster assignments */
for (i = 0; i < nelements; i++)
{ j = (int) (i + (nelements-i)*uniform());
  k = clusterid[j];
  clusterid[j] = clusterid[i];
  clusterid[i] = k;
}

return;
}


static int binomial(int n, double p)
{ const double q = 1 - p;
  if (n*p < 30.0) /* Algorithm BINV */
  { const double s = p/q;
    const double a = (n+1)*s;
    double r = exp(n*log(q)); /* pow() causes a crash on AIX */
    int x = 0;
    double u = uniform();
    while(1)
    { if (u < r) return x;
      u-=r;
      x++;
      r *= (a/x)-s;
    }
  }
  else /* Algorithm BTPE */
  { /* Step 0 */
    const double fm = n*p + p;
    const int m = (int) fm;
    const double p1 = floor(2.195*sqrt(n*p*q) -4.6*q) + 0.5;
    const double xm = m + 0.5;
    const double xl = xm - p1;
    const double xr = xm + p1;
    const double c = 0.134 + 20.5/(15.3+m);
    const double a = (fm-xl)/(fm-xl*p);
    const double b = (xr-fm)/(xr*q);
    const double lambdal = a*(1.0+0.5*a);
    const double lambdar = b*(1.0+0.5*b);
    const double p2 = p1*(1+2*c);
    const double p3 = p2 + c/lambdal;
    const double p4 = p3 + c/lambdar;
    while (1)
    { /* Step 1 */
      int y;
      int k;
      double u = uniform();
      double v = uniform();
      u *= p4;
      if (u <= p1) return (int)(xm-p1*v+u);
      /* Step 2 */
      if (u > p2)
      { /* Step 3 */
        if (u > p3)
        { /* Step 4 */
          y = (int)(xr-log(v)/lambdar);
          if (y > n) continue;
          /* Go to step 5 */
          v = v*(u-p3)*lambdar;
        }
        else
        { y = (int)(xl+log(v)/lambdal);
          if (y < 0) continue;
          /* Go to step 5 */
          v = v*(u-p2)*lambdal;
        }
      }
      else
      { const double x = xl + (u-p1)/c;
        v = v*c + 1.0 - fabs(m-x+0.5)/p1;
        if (v > 1) continue;
        /* Go to step 5 */
        y = (int)x;
      }
      /* Step 5 */
      /* Step 5.0 */
      k = abs(y-m);
      if (k > 20 && k < 0.5*n*p*q-1.0)
      { /* Step 5.2 */
        double rho = (k/(n*p*q))*((k*(k/3.0 + 0.625) + 0.1666666666666)/(n*p*q)+0.5);
        double t = -k*k/(2*n*p*q);
        double A = log(v);
        if (A < t-rho) return y;
        else if (A > t+rho) continue;
        else
        { /* Step 5.3 */
          double x1 = y+1;
          double f1 = m+1;
          double z = n+1-m;
          double w = n-y+1;
          double x2 = x1*x1;
          double f2 = f1*f1;
          double z2 = z*z;
          double w2 = w*w;
          if (A > xm * log(f1/x1) + (n-m+0.5)*log(z/w)
                + (y-m)*log(w*p/(x1*q))
                + (13860.-(462.-(132.-(99.-140./f2)/f2)/f2)/f2)/f1/166320.
                + (13860.-(462.-(132.-(99.-140./z2)/z2)/z2)/z2)/z/166320.
                + (13860.-(462.-(132.-(99.-140./x2)/x2)/x2)/x2)/x1/166320.
                + (13860.-(462.-(132.-(99.-140./w2)/w2)/w2)/w2)/w/166320.)
             continue;
          return y;
        }
      }
      else
      { /* Step 5.1 */
        int i;
        const double s = p/q;
        const double aa = s*(n+1);
        double f = 1.0;
        for (i = m; i < y; f *= (aa/(++i)-s));
        for (i = y; i < m; f /= (aa/(++i)-s));
        if (v > f) continue;
        return y;
      }
    }
  }
  /* Never get here */
  return -1;
}


static double uniform(void)
{ int z;
  static const int m1 = 2147483563;
  static const int m2 = 2147483399;
  const double scale = 1.0/m1;

  static int s1 = 0;
  static int s2 = 0;

  if (s1==0 || s2==0) /* initialize */
  { unsigned int initseed = (unsigned int) time(0);
    srand(initseed);
    s1 = rand();
    s2 = rand();
  }

  do
  { int k;
    k = s1/53668;
    s1 = 40014*(s1-k*53668)-k*12211;
    if (s1 < 0) s1+=m1;
    k = s2/52774;
    s2 = 40692*(s2-k*52774)-k*3791;
    if(s2 < 0) s2+=m2;
    z = s1-s2;
    if(z < 1) z+=(m1-1);
  } while (z==m1); /* To avoid returning 1.0 */

  return z*scale;
}


void getclustermedoids(int nclusters, int nelements, double** distance,
  int clusterid[], int centroids[], double errors[])

{ int i, j, k;
  for (j = 0; j < nclusters; j++) errors[j] = DBL_MAX;
  for (i = 0; i < nelements; i++)
  { double d = 0.0;
    j = clusterid[i];
    for (k = 0; k < nelements; k++)
    { if (i==k || clusterid[k]!=j) continue;
      d += (i < k ? distance[k][i] : distance[i][k]);
      if (d > errors[j]) break;
    }
    if (d < errors[j])
    { errors[j] = d;
      centroids[j] = i;
    }
  }
}
```

What do these errors mean? How can I fix them?

Comment: You should have been compiling with warnings in C. The compiler would have warned you. In both languages, functions must be declared before being used. In C, functions can be implicitly declared. The signature of the implicitly declared one does not match yours, though, which is bad.

Comment: Is the function *declared* before you try to use it? This is a common mistake here. Move the definition above main or add a declaration before main.

Comment: @chris what do you mean? what command should i have used?

Comment: In C and C++ we call standalone methods *functions* (just like most other languages).

Comment: @leonardovet, You should use at least `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. Your example should also be an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Minimal (all you need is one function with an empty body) and self-contained (What's that header? Is it necessary to reproduce the problem? No).

Comment: In C and C++, functions are supposed to be declared or defined before being used.

Comment: @crashmstr tank you!!! I was used to java so I didn't know that the order was important!

Comment: Here are those [warnings](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9315676f2fc863a9) I was talking about.

Answer (score 4):

You are using `kmedoids` before you have declared it. This has nothing to do with C++, the same warning should occur with a modern C compiler as well.

What you have to do is to **declare** `kmedoids` before using it (i.e. you have to write the function signature in the code somewhere above `main` -- alternatively, you can **define** it by moving the complete implementation before `main`.)

Right now, the function is undeclared at the first point where you use it (that means, the compiler doesn't know its signature and cannot check the types.)

Also: Read this for some background on how to declare functions: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function

Answer (score 0):

You need a declaration before you can use a function.

Either move your function body *before* the main method, or use a forward declaration:

```
void kmedoids (int nclusters, int nelements, double** distmatrix, int npass, int clusterid[], double* error, int* ifound);
```

This also has to be placed *before* your usage.